# Flow - check multiple fields

Tags: visual-workflow

We receive eMails via mail service in salsforce with contact details.
This information should be assigned to the contact, if the contact already exists, it should be checked whether the fields is already filled. I can use the decision item, but it checks just one field. It is possible to check the content of the variable in the process step where I add the content to the contact record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added for each field a decision and it works.

Answer (score 0):

We are able to verify a field to see if it is empty before putting a value into it.

[image: Flow snapshot]

But this is possible only one field at a time which is time consuming and does not make sense. "Flow option for updates to not overwrite existing values with blanks" is an idea right now.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U3WBQA0